# Error while using draper generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, draper

I got a problem while generating draper.

When I use `rails g draper:decorator user`

I got this : `Could not find generator draper:decorator.`

- I got draper in gem file and made bundle install.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rails g draper:decorator user
```

should be

```
rails g decorator User
```

in order to create your `UserDecorator`